# Listview with alternating color in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview

I have array of objects like the example below;

```
[{
        "id" : 13100,
        "key" : "Emlak Vergisi",
        "y" : 135638.98
    }, {
        "id" : 13154,
        "key" : "Çevre Temizlik ",
        "y" : 956.17
    }, {
        "id" : 19998,
        "key" : "Genel Tahakkuk",
        "y" : 89030.62
    }, {
        "id" : 24998,
        "key" : "Gecekondu ve So",
        "y" : 42721.07
    }, {
        "id" : 60000,
        "key" : "Ortak Gelirler",
        "y" : 827.42
    }
]
```

Is it possible to have a listview with alternating color for each item?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say this approach is cleaner:

```
 renderRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID) {

   let style = [
         styles.row, 
         {'backgroundColor': colors[rowID % colors.length]}
       ];

   return (<View style={style}/>);
 }

 let colors = ['#123456', '#654321', '#fdecba', '#abcdef'];

 let styles = StyleSheet.create({
       row: {
            // .. rows style
       }
 });
```

This way you can easily add a specail color to each row in the list (not only by even/odd type)

Answer (score 5):

Yes in renderRow, apply a different style based on rowID or rowData etc

Ex:

```
renderRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID, highlightRow) {
    if(rowID%2 === 0) {
        return (<View style={{backgroundColor: 'blue'}}/>);
    }
    return (<View style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}/>);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. RowId  was what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the rowId provided in the renderRow function. I've set up a working example [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/xcPRFA)

Render row method :

```
  renderRow = (rowData, sectionId, rowId) => {
    if (rowId % 2) {
      return (
        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
          <Text>{rowData.id}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>
          <Text>{rowData.id}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    (Provided Array).map((array, index) => {
        return (
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: (index % 2 == 0) ? '#ecf0f1' : '#fff' }}>
                <Text>{array.key}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    })
```