# How to dynamically modify the component properties style in react-native?

Tags: react-native

How to dynamically modify SimpleScrollView's backgroundColor ?
And how to get DOM in react-native?

//SimpleScrollView

```
const NUM_ITEMS=20;

class SimpleScrollView extends React.Component{
  static title= '<ScrollView>';
  static description='Component';
  itemClick(){
    //how to dynamically modify SimpleScrollView's backgroundColor

  }
  makeItem(itemsCount:number,itemStyles):Array<any>{
    let newItems=[];
    for(let i=0;i<itemsCount;i++){
      newItems[i]=(<TouchableOpacity key={i} style={itemStyles} onPress={()=>this.itemClick()}>
           <Text >{'item'+i}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    }
    return newItems;
  }
  render(){
    let items=this.makeItem(NUM_ITEMS,styles.itemWrapper);
    items[5]=(
      <ScrollView key={'scrollView'} horizontal={true} >
        {this.makeItem(NUM_ITEMS,[styles.itemWrapper,styles.horizontalItemWrapper])}
      </ScrollView>
    );
    let verticalScrollView=(
       <ScrollView style={styles.verticalScrollView}>
        {items}
       </ScrollView>

    );
    return verticalScrollView;

  }
}

var styles = React.StyleSheet.create({
  verticalScrollView: {
    margin: 10,
  },
  itemWrapper: {
    alignItems:'center',
    backgroundColor: '#dddddd',
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderWidth: 5,
    borderColor: '#a52a2a',
    padding: 20,
    margin: 5,
  },
  horizontalItemWrapper: {
    padding: 20
  },
});
```

Comment: you can use this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36150118/1206613

Comment: thanks,but this don't work for me.

Comment: Could you add a little more details about your issue?

Comment: DOM is not available in React Native.

Comment: this is my first question in stackoverflow,thanks for everybody.

Answer (score 0):

I think ou are looking for "setNativeProps"
Have a look at [direct manipulation page](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html)