# how to change one of items's style in listview ? such as a button's style or animation, React-Native

Tags: listview, react-native

React-Native

how to change one of items's style in listview ?

such as a button's style or animation on the button click event

use MVVM ？ or use this.state ? or use this.refs[] ? oh, NO!

Comment: Oh, I understand finally! render is just the re-render .
To change the effect , Just call the render event again.
So, just write all the code (e.g. change effect) in render event

Answer (score 0):

You can change item's style based on data that you have in renderRow call. Something like 
[Listview with alternating color in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36127222/listview-with-alternating-color-in-react-native/36127577#36127577)

Comment: thank you ! but I want to use the button click event , not the render event

Comment: ok. then on button click event, you will have to update the dataSource of your ListView. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listviewdatasource.html

Comment: yep, i can modify one of the data in dataSource, but can't add a effect to a button ,such as zoom-in/out.